# Meteor Mongo and Android App Sharing DB

Tags: java, android, mongodb, meteor, ddp

I am trying to create a meteor project that allows android apps to access its DB.

We have understanding of Meteor (me) and Java android development (friend).

Could anyone experienced in this field give a simple guideline on which keywords to search, or give a brief guideline of how to approach this.

I was thinking of creating a meteor server, then somehow allowing the android app to access MongoDB.

I am pretty experienced with simply making a web app with Meteor and Meteor mongo, but I have no experience opening the database to external apps.

Comment: There is a couple issues with your question. First, we're not supposed to give you links to off-site resources/tutorials (it may become dead links at a point). Second, you do not demonstrate any search on your side, you seem to ask for advices on a new issue without having done any try on it. And finally, you don't have to say "hello" or "thanks"! We like to focus solely on the question itself. You can find more data about question asking in the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). As for your query, a starting point would be "Meteor DDP implementation Android" :)

Comment: Thank you @Kyll. The only reason I asked here after lots of search was because 1.Almost no-one uses meteor in my country. 2.English is not my first language so even though I'd be looking at documentations, I didn't know if the thing I was looking at was the right approach. But I'll keep in mind the advice that you have given me for future questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor uses the [DDP protocol](https://www.meteor.com/ddp). So you can build your backend with Meteor, and then connect to it with any app (native Android app for example) through the DDP protocol by using a library for Java. A list of DDP libraries is maintained [here](http://meteorpedia.com/read/DDP_Clients). You should be able to find something for Android.